# NX Client running on OS X 10.6.4

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, nx-client, freenx

I installed freeNX on Ubuntu 10.10. My Mac OSX version is 10.6.4 and the client NX version is 3.4.0-8.

When I connect and I enter the key D, the application that is active, minimizes.
I can not understand why? I'm not very experienced but the problem is very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out.  You need to change the keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu from D to something else like Command-D for example.  This is under System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: This is not a forum, please update your previous answer or merge them together.

Comment: Great !!
I've solved a very annoying problem!
Thank you very much !!

Bye
Stefano